# Scroll excel window left to right with activex control

Tags: excel, vba, scrollbar, activex

[image]

I have six sections of employee information out of which two are shown below. Below the sections I have an activex scroll bar which I want to use from left to right. This scrollbar is different from the scrollbar in excel sheet.  Basically, currently I see Section 1  and Section 2. When I move this scroll from left to right, I should see section 2 and 3, once more when I move from left to right I should see section 3 and section 4,.... and so on.

How can I achieve this functionality.

I have tried using this piece of code here.

```
    Private Sub ScrollBar3_Change()
    Dim sc As Long
    sc = 4 + Me.ScrollBar3.Value
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = sc
    Me.ScrollBar3.Left = Me.Cells(1, sc).Left
    End Sub
```

The scrollbar currently starts from C32 and ends at AA32.
But when I click on it, the scrollbar suddenly disappears.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I am stuck at how to move the scrollbar from left to right. I have used this commands but it behaves strange. The scrollbar disappears suddenly. [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940348/excel-vba-scroll-bar-which-shift-sheet-left-or-right/12942398#12942398[link]

Comment: Did you try any of the following? https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=strict&ei=FOcxW6rdJ4vJgAastLqoBQ&q=vba+activex+scrollbar&oq=vba+ac+scrollbar&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0i7i30k1l6j0i8i7i30k1l4.9104.9691.0.11251.3.3.0.0.0.0.110.288.2j1.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.3.286...0i67k1.0.Ze3BW_zOvh8

Comment: I don't understand how this is any different from scrolling right *any other time*.  Do you mean *programmatically* move the scroll bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should the `Scrollbar.Max` should equal the maximum number of moves.  I would also suggest using `Application.Goto Range(), True` before you move the Scrollbar.

[image]

[image]

Here is an easy way to ensure that everything stays in sync:

Set the `Worksheet.ScrollArea` will limit the users ability to scroll

[image]

### User Friendly Code

```
Private Sub ScrollBar3_Change()
    Dim col As String
    col = Choose(Me.ScrollBar3.Value, "C", "N", "AB")
    Application.Goto Cells(21, col), True
    Me.ScrollBar3.Left = Columns(col).Left
End Sub
```

### Totalitarian Code

```
Private Sub ScrollBar3_Change()
    Dim col As String
    col = Choose(Me.ScrollBar3.Value, "C", "N", "AB")
    Me.ScrollArea = ""
    Application.Goto Cells(21, col), True
    Me.ScrollArea = Cells(21, col).Address
    Me.ScrollBar3.Left = Columns(col).Left
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly TinMan. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: At your service, Sir!

Answer (score 1):

Your question could be interpreted several ways (as it was somewhat vague), however I suspect this could be what you're looking for.

### `Application.Goto` Method

*Selects any range or Visual Basic procedure in any workbook, and activates that workbook (if it's not already active).*

*`expression`* . **`Goto(`** *`Reference`* `,` *`Scroll`* **`)`**

- **`expression`** A variable that represents an Application object.
- **`Reference`**   *Optional*  (Variant)   The destination. Can be a Range object, a string that contains a cell reference in `R1C1`-style notation, or a string that contains a VBA procedure name. If this argument is omitted, the destination is the last range you used the Goto method to select.
- **`Scroll`**  *Optional*  (Variant)   `True` to scroll through the window so that the upper-left corner of the range appears in the upper-left corner of the window. `False` to not scroll through the window. The default is `False` .

---

### Example:

```
Sub demo_JumpToSection()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    MsgBox "Click to go to the next section.", , "Go to column AA"
    Application.Goto ws.Range("AA1"), True

    MsgBox "Click to go to the next section.", , "Go to column BB"
    Application.Goto ws.Range("BB1"), True

    MsgBox "Click to go to the next section.", , "Go to column CC"
    Application.Goto ws.Range("CC1"), True

    MsgBox "Click to go back to the beginning.", , "Go to column A"
    Application.Goto ws.Range("A1"), True

End Sub
```

Comment: I can use this method and it is taking me to section 3 but I still can see Section 1 and 2. In place of Section1, I should now see Section 3 and in place of Section 2, I should be able to see section 4.

Comment: I like Application.Goto it can also jump to some code (as you point out).  I put it in ThisWorkbook_open to jump to the code I'm working on.